# SWIFT Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range: Sections & Rows

Tags: swift, swift5

need a little help getting grouped rows to populate their respective sections. I had it working for a second but tried to tweak the code to get rid of duplicates and missing rows. Since then I've been getting "Fatal Error"

This is for a practice project. A directory of users grouped by their departments. Using Firebase to pull the list of users. Grouping them by department then populating a table.

```
//MARK: - CELLS
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "directoryCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let departmentSections = Dictionary(grouping: directoryArray) { (user) -> String in
        return user.department
    }

    //ROW & SECTION SETUP
    let rowsInSection = Array(departmentSections.values)
    //let usersInRowData = rowsInSection[indexPath.section]
    let users = rowsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    //USER CELL INFO
    let profilePic = users.profilePic // PROFILE PHOTO GET AND DISPLAY
    let url = URL(string: profilePic); URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.profilePicView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            cell.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }).resume()

    //CELL LABELS
    cell.displayNameLabel.text = users.displayName
    cell.emailLabel.text =       users.email
    cell.officeLabel.text =      users.office
    cell.titleLabel.text =       users.title
    cell.profilePicView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    //cell.profilePicView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill;
    //cell.departmentLabel.text = users.department
    //cell.reportsToLabel.text = users.directReports
    //cell.extLabel.text = users.ext

    cell.layoutSubviews()

    return cell
}
```

I'm expecting the users to be grouped by departments. All I'm getting is: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

A table view or a collection view should display an array (one or two-dimensional) of data. A dictionary is unordered, so it is not suitable for the data model for either.

Your current code is doing a compute-intensive reconstruction of your data model on every pass through cellForRowAt. You're using `Dictionary(grouping:)` to build a dictionary, and then creating arrays out of those dictionaries, on **every** pass through `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. And you're doing it by creating a dictionary first, so the order of the sections might be different every time. Don't do that. (That is a possible cause of your crashes, since on each pass through `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:), your array of departments could be in a different order, so the number of users in each section could be different.

Also, it doesn't make any sense to build your data model in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, since the system calls `numberOfSections(in:)` first, then calls `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, then starts calling for section titles and cells. You don't show your `numberOfSections(in:)` or `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` methods, but I don't see how they could return correct information since their data models are not set up when they are first called.

I would suggest defining an array of section structs and populating it once when you first set up the table view.

```
struct SectionStruct: {
  let sectionTitle: String //Department name?
  let sectionItems: [User]
}

var sections = [SectionStruct]() //populate this as described below
```

Then, when you first set up your table view, group your array of users by department name, build an array of section structs, sort that array, and use that as your data model.

Now in your numberOfSections method would return `sections.count`.

`rowsInSection` would return `sections[section].count`

You could put the code to build your data model in a `didSet` method for your `directoryArray`:

```
var directoryArray: [User] {
  didSet {
    //Code to group your users by department, build the section structures, and sort them

    tableView?.reloadData()  //Tell the table view to reload
  }
```

Note: The above code is more like pseudo-code than actual code you could copy into your project. It's intended to point you in the right direction. Don't try to copy it into your project and complain if (when) it doesn't compile.

If you need more help refactoring your code, you are going to have to post your data structures (e.g. the type of your `directoryArray`) and the code for your `numberOfSections(in:)`, `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, and `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` data source methods. Edit your question to add your changed code at the bottom. Do not try to post code in comments. It's unformatted, and therefore unreadable.